# How to prove that $\vert x(t)\vert ^2 \le t \int_0^1 \vert x'(s) \vert \mathrm{d}x \space?$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x \in C^1[0, 1]$, such that $x(0)=0$. How to prove that 
$$\vert x(t)\vert ^2 \le t \int_0^1 \vert x'(s) \vert \mathrm{d}s  , (t\in [0,1]) \space?$$

Comment: This is false, e.g. let $x(t)=2t$, so $x'(t)=2$ and you get $|x(1)|^2=4\not \leq 2=1\cdot \int_0^12dx$. I think you need to require $x(t)\in [0,1]$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing an exponent. A version of your inequality that is valid can be obtained using the fundamental theorem of calculus and Hölder's inequality. You have
$$x(t) = x(t) - x(0) = \int_0^t x'(s) \, ds$$ so that
$$|x(t)| \le \int_0^t |x'(s)| \, ds \le \left( \int_0^t \, ds \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^t |x'(s)|^2 \, ds \right)^{1/2}$$
and thus
$$|x(t)|^2 \le t \int_0^t |x'(s)|^2 \, ds.$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality cannot hold for all such $x$, as the left-hand side is quadratic in $x$, while the right-hand side is not: try to replace $x$ by $\lambda x$, $\lambda>0$.

Here is an attempt to repair the claim
$$
\frac12(x(t)^2 - x(0)^2) = \int_0^t x(s)x'(s)dt 
\begin{cases}\le t \|x\|_{\max} \|x'\|_{\max}&\\
\le  \|x\|_{\max} \int_0^1 |x'(s)|dt& \\
\dots  \text{ other applications of H"older inequality}
\end{cases}
$$